# nodejs program doesnt build - loader issue

Tags: node.js

i am trying to build my nodejs program using node run build command, however i am getting following error.

i dont know what is going wrong

My code is on github at url https://github.com/dautpure/contentbuilderrepo2.git

C:\ContentBuilderRep1>npm run build

> content_Block_Designer__Image_with_Text@0.0.1 build C:\ContentBuilderRep1
>   webpack

Hash: 381ba61f7d50220a1694
Version: webpack 4.28.4
Time: 141ms
Built at: 01/20/2019 8:46:52 AM
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] ./src/main.js 355 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for th
is value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults
for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https
://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

ERROR in ./src/main.js 6:46
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:46)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| var sdk = new SDK();
|

> var ImageURL,Font1,Font1_Size,Font1_Color,text-input-Btm_Lft,text-input-Btm_rg
>   t,text-input-Top_Lft,text-input-Top_Rgt,text-input-Center;
>   |
>   | function debounce (func, wait, immediate) {
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 2
>   npm ERR! content_Block_Designer__Image_with_Text@0.0.1 build: `webpack`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 2
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the content_Block_Designer__Image_with_Text@0.0.1 build scrip
>   t.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
>   ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-01-20T0
8_46_52_339Z-debug.log

C:\ContentBuilderRep1>cls

Answer (score 0):

You can't use dashes (`-`) in variable names in JavaScript (see [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/9155551) for more info on this). Change the variable definitions in line 6 in `src/main.js` to be properly named. Also, in general, you should always camelcase your variables names in JS (more on this can be found in [W3Schools' JS style guide](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp)).